# JSON response showing nil

Tags: android, json

```
// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

I am using the above code but the "json" appears to be null on debugging and the program crashes. 
I have been using the famous example
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ with the same url.
It is not a problem with server , since i am receiving the response in Firefox browser.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the getJSONFromUrl function with the debugger? Are any of the exceptions in that function getting thrown?

Comment: post the url from which you are trying to get the json response or just post the json output itself. Perhaps the parser is not able to parse the response it seems.

Comment: @rahul http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ is the url.

Comment: To check where the problem, if your debugging in emulator, first check this url in emulator browser, if it invoked in browser the problem is in code not in connection.